# What could be wrong with the zip code which was sent through my emal, I seem to not see the code in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have been sent myself a compressed c++ file that I have been working on and once I downloaded the file from my gmail account after double clicking on it, I saw a load of binary or hex type data instead of my c++ program I don't know how that happened?

Comment: Invalid extension, so the OS don't know that it's an executable and therefor opens it with an texteditor?

Comment: No I'm using visual studio, there is no option I can see that will decompress it? :s

Comment: What extension does the file have, tgz, gz, zip, rar? If it's still compressed you'll need to decompress it using a tool like `tar`, `WinZip`, `WinRar`, etc.

Comment: It has a 7z extention :S, so it can be extracted using with those that you've listed righ?

Comment: never mind I've extracted it using a 7z program extracter

Answer (score 1):

You have to decompress the file before opening it.

To do this download 7-Zip http://www.7-zip.org/ or gzip http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm

At least on my system (which I didn't do the install for) 7-Zip is added to my right click options. With gzip use the command `path\gzip -d filname.ext`

Comment: How should I do this I have right clicked it but there is no option

Comment: @Arcytoi Editing with links to utilities.

Comment: Windows by default does not extract 7z files.  You will need a program that can extract the archive.